# Screenshot Fails in selenium-chromedriver If the URL contians query string parameter

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webpage-screenshot

I am using JDK 1.8.x. And I am capturing screenshots using selenium with the help of chromedriver.

Problem Facing:
If URL contains query String parameter. The screenshot looks like blank white empty page.
Example:
url =   https://example.com?a=10&model=yellow
if " ?a=10&model=yellow " the query parameter present in the url. it returns the white empty page.

```
public void saveScreeshot()
{
                DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
                WebDriver  driver = new ChromeDriver(cap);
                driver.get("https://example.com?a=10&model=yellow");
                JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
                TakesScreenshot screen = (TakesScreenshot) driver;
                File srcFile = screen.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
                File destFile = new File("myscreenshot.png");
}
```